# Replace some pattern with string

Tags: php, arrays, pattern-matching

I have an array with values like

```
$arr = array("abc-xyz","a pqr","rty'gjg","sdhf,sjh","dhd.jkyt");
```

I want to replace all the occurrences of hyphen, space, comma, dot, single quotes with underscore.

How can I do a replace with pattern.

I know I have to use

```
preg_replace($pattern,$replacewith,$string);
```

But I dont know how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this simple `preg_replace` will help you out.

**Regex:** `[\'\.,\s-]`

> **1.** `[\'\.,\s-]` this will match either of these characters `,` ,`-`,`.`, `'` or `space`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/785350)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$arr = array("abc-xyz","a pqr","rty'gjg","sdhf,sjh","dhd.jkyt");
$arr=preg_replace('/[\'\.,\s-]/', "_", $arr);
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Thank You. I will try this.